# Refactoring resource's provider in Terraform

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I have this provider blocks in my Terraform configuration:

```
# provider.tf 

provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias   = "east"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}
```

Then I have a resource using one of them:

```
resource "resource_type" "a" {
  //...
  provider = aws.east
}
```

I apply that configuration and everything is ok. So far, so good. At some point, I realize I'm not using provider `aws` anymore, but all my resources are using `aws.east` provider. I want to make it the default one, i.e. remove the alias.

How can I make this change? If I just leave `provider.tf` file like this:

```
# provider.tf

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
}
```

it doesn't work. I get this error:

> To work with resource_type.a its original
> provider configuration at
> provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].east is │
> required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
> configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still
> exist in the state. │ Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
> resource_type.a, after which you can
> remove the provider configuration again.

In reality, virtually it is the same provider. Do I really need to destroy and recreate the resource? Is there another way to do this refactor?

Comment: What is the version of your AWS provider and the version of your Terraform ? It doesn't happen in AWS 4.54.0 and TF 1.1.0

Comment: Did you also remove `provider = aws.east` from the `resource` block, or (equivalently) change it to `provider = aws`? It seems like Terraform thinks that resource is still associated with the "east" alias.